# 1 Dimensional Displacement of a Random Walk on a 2 dimensional lattice.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry, random-walk

I have a non symmetric random walk on a 2 dimensional lattice with transition probabilities $\pi_l, \pi_r, \pi_u, \pi_d$ such that $\pi_l + \pi_r + \pi_u + \pi_d = 1$. What is the distribution of the displacement of the random walk after $n$ steps along just the vertical or horizonal dimension.

I am aware of a number of potential methods for answering this question in the limit (CLT) or with an analytically intractable sum (multinomial distribution) but I was hoping for something closed form. I had been trying to work with the Pascal's triangle visualization for the [heads minus tails distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Heads-Minus-TailsDistribution.html), but using the trinomial triangle instead of Pascal's. I had been assuming $\pi_l = \pi_r$ or $\pi_d = \pi_u$ for simplicity but I can't get it to work even then.

If anyone has a solution, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to say whether we have a more tractable solution if you don't tell us the one that you find intractable.

Comment: That would be a sum over multinomial probabilities. $P(u - d = z) = \sum_z^{floor((n-z)/2)}_{j = z} \frac{n!}{j! (j-z)! (n - 2j + z)!} p_u^{j} p_d^{j - z} (1 - p_u - p_d)^{n - 2j + z}$

Comment: This is just summing over all possible up - down combinations. So if n = 5, and up - down = 3, you do Multinomial (up = 3, down = 0, other = 2) + Multinomial (up = 4, down = 1, other = 1)

Comment: OK -- that looks like the answer that I would have given. I'd be somewhat surprised if there were a way to improve on that.

Comment: That makes sense but is somewhat disappointing. I was hoping to be there might be a tractable likelihood.